# Unpacking list and assigning it to variable

Tags: python

For this code,

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(*a)
```

I would get output as
`1 2 3 4 5` as the list `a` gets unpacked.

> But what if I want to assign `*a` to a variable `x` and then print?

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
x=*a
print(x)
```

How to get the same output as the above code ?

Comment: You already have the expansion of `*a` in a variable: `a`. `*a` isn't a single argument that gets passed to `print`; it's one argument per element of `a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the same output from `print`, write `x = ' '.join(str(s) for s in a)`. However, that is not unpacking, and there is no way to use unpacking to achieve the same result here.

The unpacking operator `*` can only appear in the context of function arguments or an assignment target. Your original example uses unpacking for the arguments of the `print` function. The other way you can use unpacking is in a destructuring assignment, in which case it creates a list; for example:

```py
>>> first, *rest = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> first
1
>>> rest
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: `first, *rest = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Wow didn't know that use case. You learn everyday... :)